# Restoring Bidiagonality to a Matrix in SVD Algorithms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, matrix-decomposition

Good Afternoon,

I am implementing the Golub-Reinsch SVD algorithm and am having difficulty with a boundary case

Given a bidiagonal matrix of the form:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        b11 & b12 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & b23 \\
        0 & 0 & b33 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

A key step in the algorithm is detecting breaks along the diagonal. If this were a 4x4 matrix with the middle diagonal missing one applies givens rotations to zero out the row, decoupling the matrices. What I do not understand is what to do in the circumstance of the matrix describe above. Zeroing the bidiagonal in the second row is no issue: 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        b11 & b12 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & b33new \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

but then my implementation produces incorrect results upon convergence.

Per the references I am using, one need restore the upper quadrant to bidiagonality i.e:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        b11 & b12 & 0 \\
        0 & bnew & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & somethinghere? \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

But am a bit out of my depths. Can someone provide insight or references?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a zero at the (2,2) position, then you have got a lucky break. Apply a Givens rotations from the right to zero the $b_{12}$ element. In that case,  we have
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{b}_{11}  & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & b_{23} \\
0 & 0 & b_{33}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Now, the element $\hat{b}_{11}$ is a isolated element and it is a singular value of the matrix. Thus, you may remove the first row and the column to obtain a reduced order problem:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 0 & b_{23} \\
 0 & b_{33}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Now apply a Givens rotation from the left to kill the $b_{23}$ element. Then we get
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \hat{b}_{33}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The matrix is now diagonal and thus, $\hat{b}_{33}$  and  $0$ are singular values.